# Not able to Mock the Value from the function in PHP Mockery

Tags: php, phpunit, mockery

I have a function where I wanted to mock the value from the function but I am not successful, can you please help me

Function Inside ClassA

```
public function find() {
   ....
}
```

Function Inside TestClass

```
private function testFunction(){
  $a = ClassA::getInstance();
  $b= $a->find();
}
```

**Inside MockeryTest Case I have tried this but its still calling the find function and executing lines inside find**

```
$test= m::mock(WinaproachKeywords::class);
$test->shouldReceive('find')->andReturn('');
```

Here I wanted to mock the value and send to testFunction so that my other test cases will not have any impact on new testFunction created. Can you suggest me which is the best method and how to debug

Comment: What does `ClassA::getInstance()` exactly do? Because it seems your problem is that you are not replacing the instance with your mock due to using the singleton-pattern...